# Dealing with the ru term in an ADI Finite Difference Scheme

Tags: heston, hullwhite, differential-equations, finite-difference-method, stochastic-discount

I'm trying to code up the algorithm from [this paper](https://arxiv.org/pdf/1111.4087.pdf). The paper presents an ADI algorithm for pricing options in the Heston-Hull-White model.

The starting point is the Heston-Hull-White PDE, given below:

$$\frac{\mathrm{d}u}{\mathrm{d}t} = (\text{partial derivative terms})-ru\text{.}$$

The full PDE can be found in display (1.3) of page 2 of the linked paper. The (partial derivative terms) are split up across four matrices $A_0$, $A_1$, $A_2$, and $A_3(t)$. $A_1$ deals with partial derivatives in the $s$-direction. $A_2$ deals with partial derivatives in the $v$-direction. $A_3(t)$ deals with partial derivatives in the $r$-direction. $A_0$ deals with the mixed partial derivatives.

That leaves the $-ru$ term to be dealt with. On page 6, second paragraph from the bottom, the paper says the following:

> The $ru$ term in (1.3) is distributed evenly over $A_1$, $A_2$, $A_3(t)$.

I assume the author is alluding to some technique used in ADI methods for the Black-Scholes model, because I do not know what this means.

Questions:

1. Can you tell how the author intends for us to deal with the $ru$ term in the finite difference scheme?
2. Why is the $ru$ term split across matrices, possibly increasing computational costs, rather than being dealt with at once?

**Edit:** I have found a second mention of the $ru$ term in this thesis ( https://scripties.uba.uva.nl/document/656101 ) on page 25 (page 31 of the pdf). The quote is

> The term $−rV$ is spread evenly over the operators $L_2$ and $L_3$.

with no further explanation.